# Difference between SSH tunnels

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I'm trying to configure an SSH tunnel to bypass the mysql calls over a remote DB (remote_mysql_server) by a host that has access to it (remote_host), but I don't know what's the difference between (notice the colon `:` before the local port):

```
> ssh -f username@remote_host -L 3306:remote_mysql_server:3306 -N
> lsof -i :3306
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ssh     16797 vagrant    4u  IPv6  31697      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)
ssh     16797 vagrant    5u  IPv4  31698      0t0  TCP development:mysql (LISTEN)
```

and

```
> ssh -f username@remote_host -L :3306:remote_mysql_server:3306 -N
> lsof -i :3306
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ssh     16805 vagrant    4u  IPv6  31697      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
ssh     16805 vagrant    5u  IPv4  31698      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
```

Both of them work for me to execute the `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u dbusername -pPasswordDB database`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of `-L` option is:

```
-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
```

The `bind_address:` part is optional and if it is missing the tunnel binds to localhost only (the default behavior can be changed using `GatewayPorts` option in ssh configuration). But if you specify it, it binds to what you specify or to all interfaces if you use empty `bind_address` or `*`.

Comment: As far as I understood, bind_address parameter then is the address from the petition on port 3306 is made. This explains why for me, executing  the mysql instruction from localhost, makes no difference any of them, but in the second case I'm able to connect to MySQL using `-h development` from other machine. Thanks!